# Prevent user closing </textarea> in HTML form

Tags: html, forms, textarea

I have a HTML page output by a Python CGI-Script containing a textarea and a submit button. I'd like to prevent users from messing with the textarea field e.g. submitting malicous or any other code that could break the script through it. The script looks as simple as:

Enter your message:

How can I prevent that a user enters something like

```
innocent message.</textarea>randomcode
```

into the textarea, closing the textarea and passing a script along with the submit? So catch the user entering closing tags into the textarea?

Comment: There is not enough code to diagnose what you are doing, and what is wrong with it.  You also *need* to provide what Server Side technology you are using.

Comment: that's not how malicious injection works

Answer (score 0):

According to you description following are the drawings:
Assuming your server side technology is Python which derives an HTML page containing Form elements.

You want to prevent the user from entering the respective closing tag; basically restrict user from entering non alphanumeric characters.

Solution: Make your Python script derive a javascript function as it derives the HTML form elements;  something like which handles this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function fnCheckAlphabets()
{
    if(!((event.keyCode>43 && event.keyCode<47)||(event.keyCode>64 && event.keyCode<123)|| event.keyCode==32 ))
    { return false;  }
}
```

and call this on the eventhandler of textarea or onSubmit of the form.

You can change the keycodes suiting your requirements.

Other method would be get the values at your server side Python and sanitize the values something like this:
e.g.

```
user = form.getfirst("user", "").upper()    # This way it's safe.
```

instead of using upper you can replace unwanted characters.

reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to catch closing tags unless you are going to process the user input in a manner that causes it to be parsed as HTML. And if you are doing such things, you have bigger issues that closing tags.

Textarea input in plain text by default, plain text is what your CGI script gets, so this is just a matter of not messing around with it so that it would be fed to an HTML parser.

In particular, if you intend to display the user data as part of your own page, you should of course do that in a manner that makes browsers treat it as plain text – or sanitize it so that you only pass forward such HTML tags that you wish to allow, and turn other tags to plain text or remove them.